# Android Studio ask to update Kotlin plugin but no update available

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, androidx

I'm recently update Espresso test libraries in my Android project. Here are some part of my `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = '4.1.3'
        kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
        kotlin_ktx_version = '1.1.0'
        android_support_version = '28.0.0'
        androidx_version = '1.1.0'
        ...
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.5.1')

    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.5.0")

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:1.5.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:1.5.0")
}
```

After migrate my application test files (under *androidTest* folder) and back to the app source code, I found the following errors

[image: Some Kotlin libraries attached to this project were compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update Kotlin plugin.]

I tried to update Kotlin IDE plugin for Android Studio but I cannot since it does not have update button in Settings.

[image: Kotlin Plugin in Android Studio Settings]

I tried changing *kotlin_version* in `build.gradle` from 1.4.32 to a 1.5.31 (newer version) but it said the *kotlin_version* I specified does not the same as Kotlin IDE plugin I installed.

[image: Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.5.31) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.4.31)]

I'm using Android Studio version 4.1.3. How do I resolve those errors in the first pic?

Comment: That Android Studio is so old it's using an unfamiliar versioning scheme. The latest is 2022.2.1, I'd start by upgrading to that.